# Having troubles with JPanel, 2D Graphics, and MouseListener

Tags: java, arrays, graphics

I'm having trouble with my code as I'm trying to make a blackjack game for a final project, I have the board all made with 2D graphics and the images work, but when I try to add controls like, keyboardListener or mouseListener, or even JButtons, they never seem to work. At the moment I'm trying to use mouseListener so I can just click on the area where it says to hit, but it doesnt seem to want to work. I'm assuming it has something to do with graphics blocking the mouseListener functionality or it not being ordered properly.

I tried using JPanels and contentPanes but I could never get them to play nicely with each other.

`CardValue()` just determines a random card from an array, and paint is well paint.

I've also added in my MouseListener class at the bottom which is a separate class from Blackjack

If anyone could help me understand why MouseListener wont work over the graphics or fix my issue that would be amazing, as I'm pretty new to coding and don't fully understand graphics

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Blackjack extends Canvas {

    //Declaring Variables for images, Strings, and other things
    //Image Cards, cardback1, cardback2, dealer, you;

    static String blah;
    static int dealerstotal = 0;

    public static Stack <Integer> cards = new Stack<Integer>();

    //An array that prints out a random card and gives me the value of the cards, along with the name
    //so i can match it up with an image of the card with a match name
    public static void CardValue() {

        for (int i = 1; i<53; i++) {
            cards.add(i);
        }

        String suit1 ="", number1="";

        Random r = new Random();
        int suit = r.nextInt(4);

        switch (suit) {
        case 0: suit1 = "c"; break;
        case 1: suit1 = "d"; break;
        case 2: suit1 = "h"; break;
        case 3: suit1 = "s"; break;
        }

        int number = r.nextInt(13)+1;

        switch (number) {
        case 1: number1 = "1"; break;
        case 2: number1 = "2"; break;
        case 3: number1 = "3"; break;
        case 4: number1 = "4"; break;
        case 5: number1 = "5"; break;
        case 6: number1 = "6"; break;
        case 7: number1 = "7"; break;
        case 8: number1 = "8"; break;
        case 9: number1 = "9"; break;
        case 10: number1 = "10"; break;
        case 11: number1 = "11"; break;
        case 12: number1 = "12"; break;
        case 13: number1 = "13"; break;
        }

        blah = suit1+number1;

        if (number>=10) {
            number = 10;
        }

        if (number == 1) {

        }

        dealerstotal+=number;

        int newcard = (suit*13)+number;
        System.out.println(blah);
        cards.remove(newcard);

    }

    public Blackjack() throws Exception
    {

        //Declaring images, I //'d all these out because I didn't include the downloads for these images

        //Cards = ImageIO.read( new File(blah+ ".png") );
        //dealer = ImageIO.read( new File("dealer.jpg") );
        //you = ImageIO.read( new File("you.jpg") );
        //cardback1 = ImageIO.read(new File("redback.png"));
        //cardback2 = ImageIO.read(new File("blackback.png"));
    }

    //Creating the game board
    public void paint( Graphics g )
    {
        int l = 5;
        Color table = new Color(74, 179, 0);
        Color blues = new Color(13, 38, 163);
        String title = "Welcome to Kris' Casino";
        String dealers = "Dealers Cards";
        String dealerst = "Dealers Total: "+dealerstotal;
        String your = "Your Cards";
        String yourt = "Your Total: "+l;
        String game = "The Game is Blackjack, Goodluck";
        String hit = "Press Up to Hit";
        String stand = "Press Down to Stand";

        g.setColor(table);
        g.fillRect(0,0,10000,10000);

        //Title/Pictures

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(40,40,254,334);
        g.fillRect(40,420,254,334);
        //g.drawImage(dealer,50,50,this);
        //g.drawImage(you,50,430,this);

        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 51));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(title, 400, 90);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawString(title, 403, 93);

        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30));
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(game, 450, 140);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawString(game, 452, 142);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(400, 105, 595, 5);

        //Dealers Graphics

        //Dealers Cards
        g.drawString(dealers, 430, 240);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(450, 265, 82, 105);
        g.fillRect(550, 265, 82, 105);
        g.fillRect(650, 265, 82, 105);
        g.fillRect(750, 265, 82, 105);
        g.fillRect(850, 265, 82, 105);

        g.drawString(dealers, 432, 242);
        //g.drawImage(Cards,455,270,this);
        //g.drawImage(cardback1,555,270,this);
        //g.drawImage(cardback1,655,270,this);
        //g.drawImage(cardback1,755,270,this);
        //g.drawImage(cardback1,855,270,this);

        //Dealers Total
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(dealerst, 730, 240);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString(dealerst, 732, 242);

        //Yours Cards
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString(your, 452, 440);
        g.setColor(blues);
        g.fillRect(450, 465, 82, 105);
        g.fillRect(550, 465, 82, 105);
        g.fillRect(650, 465, 82, 105);
        g.fillRect(750, 465, 82, 105);
        g.fillRect(850, 465, 82, 105);

        g.drawString(your, 450, 438);
        //g.drawImage(cardback2,455,470,this);
        //g.drawImage(cardback2,555,470,this);
        //g.drawImage(cardback2,655,470,this);
        //g.drawImage(cardback2,755,470,this);
        //g.drawImage(cardback2,855,470,this);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString(yourt, 750, 440);
        g.setColor(blues);
        g.drawString(yourt, 748, 438);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(1116, 200, 1000, 70);

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(1032, 300, 1000, 70);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString(hit, 1134, 245);
        g.drawString(stand, 1050, 345);
    }

    //Here is where I'm having my issues, Whenever I add "frame.add(new Blackjack());" mouseListener doesnt work
    //mouseListener only works when I don't have "frame.add(new Blackjack());"
    //Im guessing this is some kind of issue to do with graphics ontop of the mouseListener/JFrame 
    //disabling it from working
    public static void Frame() throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Kris' Casino");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(new ClickListener());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.add(new Blackjack());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CardValue();
        Frame();
    }
}
```

Here is the second class for the mouseListener

```java
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class ClickListener extends MouseAdapter {

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getX() + "," + e.getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need that switch statement to convert a number to a string. You can do either `String number1 = number +""` or `String number1 = Integer.toString(number);`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Frame() throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Kris' Casino");
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(new ClickListener());  // *** 1 ***
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.add(new Blackjack());                                    // *** 2 ***
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Note that you're adding your MouseListener to the JFrame's contentPane at `*** 1 ***`, and then **you're covering the contentPane up with the Blackjack component** at `*** 2 ***` and so the MouseListener can't work since the component that it is listening to has been fully covered, with a heavy-weight component (a Canvas object).

Solution: add the MouseListener to the component displayed, the Blackjack component

Also:

- Don't extend Canvas but rather JPanel
- Override the JPanel's paintComponent method
- Always call the super's painting method within your override, thus call `super.paintComponent(g);` if you override paintComponent or `super.paint(g);` if you override the paint method.

Comment: I just changed the order of the components and changed Canvas to JFrame and it seems to work now, so thank you, could you possibly go into more detail about "Override the JPanel's paintComponent method" and "Always call the super's painting method within your override"

Comment: @KrisPham: "changed Canvas to JFrame" -- good lord, no, don't do this as you should never draw directly in a JFrame, since you're overriding key functionality in a dangerous way. As for more on override paintComponent, please have a look at [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html): introductory tutorial to Swing graphics.

Comment: Wait so should I change it back to Canvas? I'm sorry if this is forward but are you busy at the moment? If not is there any way we could like video call on discord or something if possible? I just don't want to waste your time going back and fourth like this if theres a faster way. If not no worries I will try my best to understand what you're saying

Comment: Please re-read my answer and comment above as it answers your question

Comment: @KrisPham: And no, we cannot video chat. This isn't a help site but a question and answer site and we are all volunteers. Your original question has been answered.

Comment: Okay I'm so sorry, I didn't mean to offend you at all. Thank you so much for your help and have a nice day